# discord.js - Receiving error when trying to retrieve userID of .repliedUser

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

Here’s the situation:

In my server I have a bot (not mine) that replies to specific user actions with a message containing an embed that has the word “Done!” in the description. I want to set it up so that once this bot sends the “Done!” message the user it replied to receives a role.

Today being the first day I’ve ever used javascript means I’m not surprised I’ve encountered an error, however I simply could not figure out how to fix it. I tried working around the error by attempting to achieve my intended result by different methods, but I cannot find an actual alternative so I’ve ended up back at the error.

The code that I’m experiencing the error with is this:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "1001628984829816952");
  let member = message.mentions.repliedUser();
  let done = "done!"
  if (done(w => message.embeds.description.toLowerCase().includes(w))) {
    member.roles.add(role);
  }
});
```

and the error I'm receiving is this:

```
 let member = message.mentions.repliedUser();
                               ^

TypeError: message.mentions.repliedUser is not a function
```

I'm a bit confused as I was sure `.repliedUser` is [valid](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=repliedUser), although this may be my absolute inexperience with javascript shining through.

On a side note, I believe I have the necessary intents enabled:

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
```

so those shouldn't be a problem.

What I've tried by means of my own intuitive bumbling is replacing `message.mentions.repliedUser()` with `message.mentions.repliedUser.get()` since I've seen `.get` used at the end a bit like that and it sounds about right (I'm laughing at my own explanation here, please bear with me...), however I receive a different error with that in place:

```
  let member = message.mentions.repliedUser.get();
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')
```

I'm not surprised by this result, though, (even if I don't fully understand what it's trying to tell me...) since `.repliedUser` isn't recognised anyways.

I'm not really sure where to go from here, especially since there seems to be no mention of `.repliedUser` anywhere on the internet except for the discord.js docs, and also because much of the general help for discord.js is still aimed at v13, whereas I'm running v14, and the two are not compatible.

Any and all help is much appreciated, and I'm sorry if this question is stupid and the answer to it is incredibly rudimentary, which I'm guessing it is. I also hope that my code is readable; it seems to mostly work, except for the error, but it is also mostly patchwork so it could just be some nonsense that's pretending to work.

*(At least this has convinced me to get into javascript properly, even if only for my own peace of mind.)*

Comment: Plural form of `mentions` suggests that this is an array.. In the docs you sent `repliedUser` is not a function also. Try `message.mentions[0].repliedUser`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `message.mentions[0].repliedUser` gives me the error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'repliedUser')`
I'm not sure what this means

Comment: Why do you still trying to add these `()` at the end when `repliedUser` is not a function? Try to `console.log(message)` and see what you have inside.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ah, because i did not know you should not include them - I'm a complete beginner. Thank you. I still receive the same error after removing them, though, and `console.log(message)` isn't outputting anything in the console. I may have set it up wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, message.mentions.repliedUser is of type `?User`. You are expecting it to be of type `(...) => ?User`, which it isn't.

Simple fix, just replace `.repliecUser()` with `.repliedUser`.